# Why i'm getting a white screen in map app

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new here and also new in programming. 
I'm making map, I have followed a lot of tutorials, all of them very simillar but I don't know why my app doesn't work. The app doesn't crash, but when I open the map appears the app title and a white screen where the map should appear. Do you know why is this happening?

Here are my app manifest, the activity:main.xml and the mainactivity.java, maybe here's the error that I can't find.

Also if helps logcat says me: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

APP MANIFEST

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tdr.mapa1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
      android:name="com.tdr.mapa1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="permission_name"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.tdr.mapa1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

   <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" 
                  android:required="false"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.tdr.mapa1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >   

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="<API_KEY>"/>

    </application>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </manifest>
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.tdr.mapa1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: are you using the emulator?

Comment: You must have some Views in your RelativeLayout, in your case i suppose MapView

Comment: @user2340612 No, i'm testing it directly on the phone.

Comment: @Android Do you mean in the Graphycal layout of the Main Activity? If yes, I can see the title of the app and the white secreen.

Comment: in the xml file, like i did in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your error:

```
Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

doesn't mean anything and you should node pay any attention to it.

Second, both meta-data tags should be inside of the application scope, like so:

```
...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="<API_KEY>"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 </application>
```

Lastly, you are not actually creating any map object in your activity layout file, what you have there is an empty `RelativeLayout` and hence the empty white screen. What you need is to add an `MapFragment` in there or `SupportMapFramgnet` depending on your target api. (In your case it would be `MapFragment`.)

Like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can get more detailed information from this blog post I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 2):

See here,just change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and **make sure that generate api key with package name which is mentioned in android manifest file and your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space only.**

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

And make sure following steps done correct or not:

Steps:
* to ensure that device has Google Play services APK
* to install Google Play Service rev. more than 2

[image]

- to create project at https://code.google.com/apis/console/
- to enable "Google Maps Android API v2"
  [image]
- to register of SHA1 in project (**NOW, YOU NEED WRITE SHA1;your.app.package.name**) at APIs console and get API KEY
- to copy directory ANDROID_SDK_DIR/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib to root of your project
- to add next line to the YOUR_PROJECT/project.properties

`android.library.reference.1=google-play-services_lib`

- to add next lines to the YOUR_PROJECT/proguard-project.txt

`-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {`

`protected Object[][] getContents();`

`}`

Okay, now you ready to create your own Google Map app with using Google Map APIs V2 for Android.

If you create application with min SDK = 8, please use android support library v4 + SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.

After got this let me know.