# google maps apiv2 failed to load map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I try to show google maps on my aplication but i can´t 
this is the errors

```
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-17 03:54:14.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

manifest.xml
I add all permisions that i found in internet and i thing that the problem its not here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.flow"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="4"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
            <permission
                android:name="com.example.flow.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true"/> 
            <uses-permission android:name="com.example.flow.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.flow.Flow"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyDNIkpmmuFyj2vpTfAPtnqWpf-EX94bRl0"/>
    <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

activity_flow.xml
add fragment and SupportMapFragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Flow" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

flow.java

```
 package com.example.flow;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Flow extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flow);    
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    }
}
```

Comment: thats all my code i hope that can help me

Comment: @user3159679 post the full manifest

Comment: @user3159679 where is activity declared in manifest file. where is the start of application tag?

Comment: Once go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007987/why-im-getting-a-white-screen-in-map-app/21011784#21011784) link which I answered in another post.. May it helps you. If you have any queries let me know.

Comment: this point i tried to do, but when i load the proyect send me warning in the icon -to copy directory ANDROID_SDK_DIR/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib to root of your project

Comment: Raghunandan sorry man i dont copy all manifest.xml because stockoverflow dont let me but now i post

Comment: Did you add Google play services lib to your project? and make sure your project and library project should be present in same work space.

Comment: yes i do, but of this directory extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Comment: You need to move that project in to your project's work space.

Comment: i tried like you said copy google-play-servic‌​es_lib to my proyect root but send me warning in the icon aplication and dont let me run, send that i have errors

Comment: which warning you are getting. can you post that warning

Comment: this is the error google-play-services_lib] Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one

Comment: You need to add target to your google play service lib project
goto project-->right click-->properties-->Android-->select target-->apply..>OK
thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess from this line `at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)` you might have forget to implement `onActivityResult` method in your class. Make sure if you are starting activity as `startActivityForResult()` then you must have to implement this method.

Comment: thanks but i implemet you say this    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.flow, menu);
        return true;
    }

Comment: @user3159679 Please post your java code. This posted code is not sufficient.

Comment: @user3159679 In your `Flow` you have not started any activity which returns the result back to your `Flow` activity that is why its throwing nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your manifest has

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.flow.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.flow.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Also make sure that you have your key (debug or release) set in the maps api console.

Comment: these permissions are not required. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: @user3159679 these two are no longer required you can check the docs

Comment: Raghunandan thans bro i got it, some other idea i was try with some 10 tutorials i read the documentation of google maps apiv2 and i can´t show the map