# Google maps V2 showing a white screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I am only getting a white screen with buttons for zooming and have tried to solve this problem from a lot of answers about the same question but nothing is working out for me.So can anyone tell me what is wrong here.

Logcat :

```
01-29 16:48:48.703: D/dalvikvm(16910): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
01-29 16:48:48.703: W/dalvikvm(16910): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 36
01-29 16:48:48.703: D/dalvikvm(16910): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
01-29 16:48:48.703: D/dalvikvm(16910): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
01-29 16:48:48.882: D/dalvikvm(16910): GC_CONCURRENT freed 194K, 46% free 3079K/5639K, external 412K/517K, paused 4ms+4ms
01-29 16:48:49.078: D/dalvikvm(16910): GC_CONCURRENT freed 129K, 42% free 3517K/6023K, external 412K/517K, paused 5ms+4ms
01-29 16:48:49.218: W/dalvikvm(16910): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/r; (643)
01-29 16:48:49.218: W/dalvikvm(16910): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/r;' failed
01-29 16:48:49.218: W/dalvikvm(16910): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ao/an; (6521)
01-29 16:48:49.226: W/dalvikvm(16910): Link of class 'Lmaps/ao/an;' failed
01-29 16:48:49.226: W/dalvikvm(16910): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ae/i; (5640)
01-29 16:48:49.226: W/dalvikvm(16910): Link of class 'Lmaps/ae/i;' failed
01-29 16:48:49.226: E/dalvikvm(16910): Could not find class 'maps.ae.i', referenced from method maps.af.al.a
01-29 16:48:49.226: W/dalvikvm(16910): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 5490 (Lmaps/ae/i;) in Lmaps/af/al;
01-29 16:48:49.226: D/dalvikvm(16910): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0091
01-29 16:48:49.257: D/dalvikvm(16910): VFY: dead code 0x0093-00a0 in Lmaps/af/al;.a (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;Z)Lmaps/af/al;
01-29 16:48:49.523: D/dalvikvm(16910): GC_CONCURRENT freed 263K, 43% free 3655K/6343K, external 412K/517K, paused 5ms+4ms
01-29 16:48:49.929: D/dalvikvm(16910): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 232K, 41% free 3784K/6407K, external 437K/517K, paused 53ms
01-29 16:48:50.476: D/libEGL(16910): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hgl.so
01-29 16:48:50.609: D/dalvikvm(16910): GC_CONCURRENT freed 199K, 40% free 3933K/6535K, external 550K/1036K, paused 23ms+4ms
01-29 16:48:50.632: E/(16910): Creating OpenGL 1.1 Session
01-29 16:48:50.632: D/BRCM_EGL(16910): eglCreateContext() context: 0xf0920, VC context 1, Thread 16929
01-29 16:48:50.640: D/BRCM_EGL(16910): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x1e56e0, VC surface: 1, Thread: 16929
01-29 16:48:50.640: D/BRCM_EGL(16910): eglMakeCurrent(0xf0920, 0x1e56e0, 0x1e56e0) Thread: 16929
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vallabh.googlemapspractice"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.vallabh.googlemapspractice.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My API key here"/>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Activity.java

```
package com.vallabh.googlemapspractice;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
GoogleMap map;
double lat;
double lan;
boolean flag = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(onSavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: regenerate the key and make sure you have enabled maps for android in the api console

Comment: i regenerated the key and the maps for android is also enabled but nothing happened

Comment: Are you trying it in emulator or real device?

Comment: on a device..its not working on the emulator as well.When i generated the key i even gave the package name properly

Comment: which package name you used to generate api key? You need to generate it with package name which is mentioned in manifest i.e, com.vallabh.googlemapspractice but not general package name?

Comment: yes i did it with com.vallabh.googlemapspractice

Comment: Key for Android apps (with certificates)
API key:  
AIzaSyA-kGS4dik044tCjzdQ6J3RGpPrVF90m70
Android apps:  
B6:11:65:86:52:61:CE:65:CB:2E:8E:CB:4A:A6:0B:E0:87:35:EA:9A;com.vallabh.googlemapspractise
Activated on:  Jan 29, 2014 3:04 AM
Activated by:  vallabh.lakade@gmail.com – you

Comment: Its showing an error like 'could not find class maps.ae.i' referenced from method maps.af.al.a

Comment: post your map xml code please

Comment: i have added activity_main.xml in the question

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue turn out that Google Map APi was enabled on project console . make sure Google Map API is enabled .[image: Enable map API]

Answer (score 2):

Add this tag before the `uses-permision` tags in the `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.vallabh.googlemapspractice.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

And add this `uses-permission` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.vallabh.googlemapspractice.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Once follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007987/why-im-getting-a-white-screen-in-map-app/21011784#21011784) step by step process which I answered in previous question. Then let me know if any queries.

Comment: Google Maps Android API V2 is on and i have also used the correct package name

Comment: Its showing an error like 'could not find class maps.ae.i' referenced from method maps.af.al.a

Answer (score 0):

With the latest google document it seems like you no longer need MAPS_RECEIVE anymore.

I had the same issue while transporting my project from one machine to another. 
Turns out the issue is you do need to re-generate the key.

Remember you did this step? (following https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

the SHA1 sequence is different for different machine. So eventually worked for me is to get a new API key with this different SHA1 sequence. Then use this new API key in the project manifest file. 
This had solved my issue.