# GoogleMaps API error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-mapview

I’m experiencing troubles making the GoogleMaps API work in my app. When I open my app either on the emulator or on my Galaxy S4, the maps appears blank with only the grey grid showing. When I run the app in the emulator I get an error in the eclipse console:
“Server returned: 3”

thanks

//activity_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="APIKEY"
       android:clickable="true"
/>
```

// GoogleActivtiy.java

```
package com.example.thetest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;


 public class GoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity {

       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
                return true;
        }
}
```

//logcat

```
04-22 18:33:48.410: W/System.err(872): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
04-22 18:33:48.420: W/System.err(872):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
04-22 18:33:48.420: W/System.err(872):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
04-22 18:33:48.420: W/System.err(872):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
04-22 18:33:48.420: W/System.err(872):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
04-22 18:33:48.420: W/System.err(872):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
04-22 18:33:48.420: W/System.err(872):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-22 18:33:48.830: W/System.err(872): IOException processing: 26
```

Comment: Have you set up an Android API key in the API Console?

Comment: are you using google map api v2 ???

Answer (score 0):

For getting Google map in android emulator there is a step by step procedure which I answered in previous question. For that refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094787/map-not-getting-in-emulator-android-api-v2)

For getting it in real device make sure are you follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007987/why-im-getting-a-white-screen-in-map-app/21011784#21011784) steps..

Answer (score 0):

you are using the old way of google map. at present this way is not using and google have announce that this method of google map has not supported further. so please use Google Map V2. you have a tutorial in following link which is good for totally beginner also

[Google Map Api V2 for Android](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)